# Where was Hela imprisoned?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

At the (relative) beginning of *Thor: Ragnarok*, Hela returns to Asgard after a long absence.

Odin expelled her—he mentions that he can’t hold her off any longer. Hela mentions that she was banished. But where to? I don’t recall it being mentioned in the movie.

The obvious answer is to [Niflheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niflheim), but given that the Marvel universe (and the Marvel Cinematic universe) has altered many things, this isn’t certain.

Where was Hela banished *to*?

Comment: Possibly, it isn't a place or why would she return once Odin died. Obviously, Odin created a pocket dimension using Odinforce to lock her in.

Comment: The "Hela (MCU)" article from [_villians.wikia.com_](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Hela_(Marvel_Cinematic_Universe)) mentions that "Able to defeat her but incapable of killing her,Odin decided to dispose of Hela by banishing her to a realm called Hel, where his life force would be the only lock to keep her from escaping."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### He imprisoned her in Hel.

Hela was in fact imprisoned in Hel which is why in *Avengers: Infinity War*, when Thor and Rocket were talking on their way to Knowhere, [Thor said](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War):

> Before my father died, he told me I had a half-sister...that he imprisoned in Hel. Then she returned home, and stabbed me in the eye, so... I had to kill her.

In Norse mythology Hela is the goddess of death which also tells the fact that she was part of the afterlife.

Comment: Was Hel named Hel before Hela got imprisoned there?